# swift: while creating(?) imageview, it expected ',' separator error

Tags: iphone, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var simpleImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        simpleImageView.image = UIImage(named:"#imageLiteral(resourceName: "doodle")")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

"doodle" is my AssetCatalog image set name.
in line simpleImageView ~ doodle")"), there's an error "expected "," separator". i just followed my book...

Comment: I do not think there should be `"`  around the `#imageLiteral`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `UIImage(named:)` initializer and `#imageLiteral` at the same time. ***You can't.*** You must use either one of these.

I would prefer `imageLiteral` because it checks the literal's validity at compile time and it looks better in Xcode. You should do it like this:

```
simpleImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "doodle")
```

As you can see, you don't need to write `UIImage(named:)` because `#imageLiteral` *represents* a `UIImage` object.

Alternatively, use the `UIImage(named:)` initializer like this:

```
simpleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "doodle")
```

To use the initializer, you just pass in a simple string of the name of the image you want.

Comment: Currently image literals have many problems in Xcode. The way they are converted to image make it very hard to modify them. I would prefer the code to stay the same and see the image somewhere else, e.g. on the margin.

Comment: @Sulthan What do you mean by "see the image somewhere else"? What margin?

Comment: Have you ever worked in jetbrains editors? See for example the image of CSS editation in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2017.2/colorPreview.png . It doesn't change the code but it uses the left margin to show the color/image.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes I have, and I do think that showing the image in the margin is better. But unfortunately Xcode does not have that, in which case I prefer image literals because I often mistype the image name.

Comment: @정초이 if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
simpleImageView.image  = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Apple.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the image literal you can use convenience `init(imageLiteralResourceName:)` initializer:

```
 simpleImageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "doodle")
```